# User Get-ADUser to list all properties and export to .csv

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to go through a list of users I have and would like to get a few properties (DisplayName, Office) to show in a table then convert the table to a .csv.

I've been working with:

```
$Users = gc "C:\scripts\Users.txt
foreach ($User in $Users) {
Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties DisplayName,Office
}
```

And that's fine, I can combine it with "select DisplayName,Office" but if I do an "Out-File -append" it just looks terrible. I think I should do this with an array or hash table but I've been reading up on them and don't really understand how I would automate one that can be exported. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Query all users and filter by the list from your text file:

```
$Users = Get-Content 'C:\scripts\Users.txt'
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName,Office |
    Where-Object { $Users -contains $_.SamAccountName } |
    Select-Object DisplayName, Office |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
```

`Get-ADUser -Filter '*'` returns all AD user accounts. This stream of user objects is then piped into a [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) filter, which checks for each object if its `SamAccountName` property is contained in the user list from your input file (`$Users`). Only objects with a matching account name are passed forward to the next step of the pipeline. The output can be limited by [selecting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176955.aspx) the relevant properties before exporting the data.

You can further optimize the code by replacing the `-contains` operator with [hashtable lookups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx):

```
$Users = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\scripts\Users.txt' | ForEach-Object { $Users[$_] = $true }

Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName,Office |
    Where-Object { $Users.ContainsKey($_.SamAccountName) } |
    Select-Object DisplayName, Office |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Well that was fast and it works well. Can you explain how/why that worked though? I understand the export, but the | ? { $Users - contains $_SamAccountName } | is what gets me. Also, is there a nice way to have it include just the DisplayName and Office? This gave me the DisplayName and Office but included a few other categories. Thanks again, you seem very knowledgeable.

Comment: @noz3r0 See updated answer. I hope that clarifies things for you.

Comment: The method described in the comment below is significantly more efficient because it is querying only the accounts in the list. This solution is selecting every single account in the domain and returning its properties before the "Where" clause.

Comment: @Trix *"The method described in the comment below is significantly more efficient because it is querying only the accounts in the list."* Umm... that makes it significantly **less** efficient, because repeated queries for individual users are far more expensive than fetching a limited number of properties for all users just once.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - please see my response in the main thread, since I wanted to show some real-world examples.

Comment: @Trix Your measurements are correct for small sample sizes compared to the total user count. When I ran some benchmarks against a test AD (~2000 random users in 3 OUs) the results showed that the query-all approach had relatively constant execution times regardless of the number of elements in `$userlist`, whereas execution times for distinct queries grew linear with the number of elements in `$userlist` and started exceeding the query-all execution times at ~15% of the total user count.

Answer (score 9):

This can be simplified by completely skipping the where object and the $users declaration.  All you need is:

**Code**

```
get-content c:\scripts\users.txt | get-aduser -properties * | select displayname, office | export-csv c:\path\to\your.csv
```

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is to return only the properties you need rather than all of them for each account selected. `get-content c:\scripts\users.txt | get-aduser -properties displayname,office | select displayname,office ...`

Answer (score 0):

@AnsgarWiechers - it's not my experience that querying everything and then pruning the result is more efficient when you're doing a targeted search of known accounts. Although, yes, it is also more efficient to select just the properties you need to return.

The below examples are based on a domain in the range of 20,000 account objects.

```
measure-command {Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName,st }
...
Seconds           : 16
Milliseconds      : 208

measure-command {$userlist | get-aduser -Properties DisplayName,st}
...
Seconds           : 3
Milliseconds      : 496
```

In the second example, $userlist contains 368 account names (just strings, not pre-fetched account objects).

Note that if I include the `where` clause per your suggestion to prune to the actually desired results, it's even more expensive.

```
measure-command {Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName,st |where {$userlist -Contains $_.samaccountname } }
...
Seconds           : 17
Milliseconds      : 876
```

Indexed attributes seem to have similar performance (I tried just returning `displayName`).

Even if I return all user account properties in my set, it's more efficient. (Adding a select statement to the below brings it down by a half-second).

```
measure-command {$userlist | get-aduser -Properties *}
...
Seconds           : 12
Milliseconds      : 75
```

I can't find a good document that was written in ye olde days about AD queries to link to, but you're hitting every account in your search scope to return the properties. This discusses the basics of doing effective AD queries - scoping and filtering: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms808539.aspx#efficientadapps_topic01

When your search scope is "*", you're still building a (big) list of the objects and iterating through each one. An LDAP search filter is always more efficient to build the list first (or a narrow search base, which is again building a smaller list to query).